# Different layout with Layout of PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, settings, preferencescreen

I use PreferenceScreen for my Settings.

The acticitie works fine with the *@android:style/Theme.Dialog* theme.
So a dialog appears center in my main activitie !

It works fine on ldpi, mdpi et hdpi but doesn't work on xhdpi.
The switchpreferences overlay my title item ! A margin is created =s

Good (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi): http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9212/sty.png

Bad (xhdpi): http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/3529/c7k.png

How delete this ?
Thank's !

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Réglages ! -->
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Capture categorie ! -->
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_label_capture"
        android:key="pref_key_capture_settings" >
    <!-- Vitesse -->
    <ListPreference
            android:key="speed_preferences"
            android:title="@string/settings_speed"
            android:summary="@string/settings_speed_summary"
            android:entries="@array/speedUnity"
            android:entryValues="@array/speedValues" />
    <!-- Mode -->
    <ListPreference
            android:key="mode_preferences"
            android:title="@string/settings_mode"
            android:summary="@string/settings_mode_summary"
            android:entries="@array/mode"
            android:entryValues="@array/modeValues" />
    <!-- Historique -->
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="lock_preferences"
            android:title="@string/settings_historic"
            android:summary="@string/settings_historic_summary"
            android:switchTextOn="@string/settings_historic_lock"
            android:switchTextOff="@string/settings_historic_unlock"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
<!-- Stockage -->
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_storage"
        android:key="pref_key_storage">
    <!-- Sauvegarde -->
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="save_preferences"
            android:title="@string/settings_save"
            android:summary="@string/settings_save_summary"
            android:switchTextOff="@string/settings_save_manual"
            android:switchTextOn="@string/settings_save_auto"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Code :

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
protected Method mLoadHeaders = null;
protected Method mHasHeaders = null;

/**
 * Checks to see if using new v11+ way of handling PrefsFragments.
 * @return Returns false pre-v11, else checks to see if using headers.
 */
public boolean isNewV11Prefs() {
    if (mHasHeaders!=null && mLoadHeaders!=null) {
        try {
            return (Boolean)mHasHeaders.invoke(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle aSavedState) {
            //onBuildHeaders() will be called during super.onCreate()
    try {
        mLoadHeaders = getClass().getMethod("loadHeadersFromResource", int.class, List.class );
        mHasHeaders = getClass().getMethod("hasHeaders");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    }
    super.onCreate(aSavedState);
    if (!isNewV11Prefs()) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
    ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("speed_preferences");
    switch (Integer.valueOf(sharedPref.getString("speed_preferences", "0"))) {
        case Vitesse.KMH:
            pref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_summary) + " : " + getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_kmh));
            break;
        case Vitesse.MS:
            pref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_summary) + " : " + getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_ms));
            break;
        case Vitesse.MPH:
            pref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_summary) + " : " + getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_mph));
            break;
    }
    pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("mode_preferences");
    if (sharedPref.getString("mode_preferences", Preferences.Mode.SIMPLE.toString()).equals(Preferences.Mode.SIMPLE.toString())) {
        pref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_summary) + " : " + getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_single));
    } else {
        pref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_summary) + " : " + getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_burst));
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
    Preference pref;
    if ((pref = findPreference(s)) instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
        if (listPref.getKey().equals("speed_preferences")) {
            listPref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_summary) + " : " + listPref.getEntry());
        } else if (listPref.getKey().equals("mode_preferences")) {
            listPref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_summary) + " : " + listPref.getEntry());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> aTarget) {
    try {
        mLoadHeaders.invoke(this,new Object[]{R.xml.settings,aTarget});
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    }
}

static public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle aSavedState) {
        super.onCreate(aSavedState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        Preference pref;
        if ((pref = findPreference(s)) instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
            if (listPref.getKey().equals("speed_preferences")) {
                listPref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_speed_summary) + " : " + listPref.getEntry());
            } else if (listPref.getKey().equals("mode_preferences")) {
                listPref.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_mode_summary) + " : " + listPref.getEntry());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Frankly noone can imagine your problem here or anywhere. We need to see code. Else you are just one more bad question for us.\

Comment: I use this code for use PreferenceScreen http://www.blackmoonit.com/2012/07/all_api_prefsactivity/

Comment: Please dont make people open 4 tabs to help you. Post the question on SO completely stating your exact problem. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: I added the code ! My problem is on XHDPI the settings doesn"t has the same visualisation that the other resolutions. Look the 2 images

Comment: I have reversed by downvote and given you a upvote too, so that you can get some attention on your question. Please paste the images in the question too. Links are bad.

Comment: I can't, I need more reputation too put images...